# Group theory $\left(\mathbb{Z}/{a^r \mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

let $a,r\in\mathbb{N},r>3$, how to prove

The group of elements in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/{a^r \mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$congruent to 1 modulo $a^3$ is cyclic;

Moreover,all its subgroups are of the form $\left\{x\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/{a^r \mathbb{Z}}\right)|x\equiv1 ~mod ~m\right\}$ where $a^3|m,m|a^r$.

I really have no idea on this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is a prime power, you can use the existence of a primitive root modulo $a$ to deduce the result: More precisely, $(\mathbb{Z}_{a^r})^*$ will be cyclic, so the subgroup of elements congruent to $1$ modulo $a^3$ will also be cyclic (subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic).

For the general case, consider the prime factorization $a=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots _k^{\alpha_k}$. By the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and the fact that the units of a direct product are the direct product of the units in each factor, $G=(\mathbb{Z}_{a^r})^*$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{\alpha_1 r}})^* \times \cdots \times (\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{\alpha_k r}})^*.$ Now, it easy to see that the subgroup of $G$ consisting of elements congruent to $1$ modulo $a^3$ is the direct product $G_1 \times \cdots \times G_k$ where $G_i$ is the (cyclic) subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{\alpha_i r}})^*$ consisting of those elements which are congruent to $1$ modulo $a^3$. Hence, the desired subgroup is the direct product of cyclic groups of coprime orders, so it must also be cyclic.

Edit: As pointed out by the OP in the comments, the argument using the CRT is not right. I will leave my answer nonetheless in case it helps someone coming up with a solution.

Comment: thanks for help. But, CRT only gives us $(\mathbb{Z}_{a^r})\cong(\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{\alpha_1 r}}) \times \cdots \times (\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{\alpha_k r}}).$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z})^*\ncong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^*\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a counter example.